# Can't Pull photo from instagram api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, instagram-api

I am trying to pull the most recent photo from an instagram profile in ionic-framework.

I am using this endpoint: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent
 but when I call it, I am getting undefined objects.

Here is my code:
controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, TwitterREST, PhotoService) {
    PhotoService.GetFeed().then(function (result) {
        $scope.items = result;
    })
```

my factory:

```
.factory('PhotoService', function ($http, $q) {
    var BASE_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1311251426/media/recent/?access_token=2e895efe81754bcc853dbde48ca32dae&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    var items = [];// min tag id - for fetching newer photos

    return {
        GetFeed: function () {
            return $http.jsonp(BASE_URL).then(function (response) {
                alert(response.data.data);
                items = response.data.data;
                alert(items);
                return items;

            });
        },
    }
});
```

and my html:

```
<ion-item >
            <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img ng-src="{{items.user.profile_picture}}" ng-if="items.user.profile_picture.startsWith('https')">
                <h2>{{items.user.username}}</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <img ng-src="{{items.images.low_resolution.url}}" ng-if="items.images.low_resolution.url.startsWith('https')">
                <p>
                    {{items.caption.text}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </ion-item>
```

why are my calls pulling no data? I am not getting anything in the error message so I assume I may be missing some angular step. I am somewhat new to angular and still figuring some things out.

Comment: i think u are in sandbox mode ?

Comment: how do I change that? It shows my account as in sandbox users but no clear way to change it

Comment: u cannot, u have to first complete app in sandbox and get reviewed and approved by instagram, and then u can change to live mode.

Comment: u can get response for the user photos for the user that has been added to your sandbox

Comment: So I tried that right after and it still doesn't work.

Comment: try this api: api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/